# Implement marker in eclipse source view editor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

How do I can implement the blue marker (marker annotation) in the Eclipse source view editor?

[image]

Comment: Your own editor or an existing editor? For an existing editor you will have to look at the APIs and extension points it provides to see if this is possible.

Comment: the existing editor I couldn't find any proper solution for this.

Comment: You wouldn't do this for an existing editor. It's the only one that can decide what that specific range indication should be, and that is probably why it is not a regular Annotation. Nothing else paints in the vertical ruler across multiple lines like that.

Comment: Is it possible to patch the CDT plugin  and override the current marker ?

Answer (score 0):

Markers exist on-disk, that's an Annotation (some Annotations are created based on Markers). That one's called the range indicator. It's special in that you don't add and remove it from the annotation model, you just keep it up to date with selection changes using `org.eclipse.jface.text.source#ISourceViewer.setRangeIndication(int, int, boolean)`.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the custom red color marker like the blue color marker, for all the methods in the source file, does this can be implement using marker annotation ?  Any proper recommendation for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String MARKER_ID = "com.test.marker";

@param res=file full path line= line number in file you want to show the marker

public static IMarker createMarker(IResource res, int line) throws CoreException {

    IMarker marker = null;
    // note: you use the id that is defined in your plugin.xml

    if (res != null) {
        marker = res.createMarker(MARKER_ID);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, 
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
    }
    return marker;

}
```

Plugin.xml

Use this extension points

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
  <type
        markerType="com.ashling.comrv.marker"
        name="com.test.marker">
  </type>
```